# Rendering issues when editing a comment

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comments

I was editing a comment I wrote, and when I clicked on the button to save the edit, the page became as in the following screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

As you see, the comment is replaced with the content that should be in the header. This is the second time I notice this, but I don't recall if I was editing a comment also in that case.

If this makes any difference, I am using Safari 5.1.2. on Mac OS X 10.7.3. The question for which I was editing the comment is [Strange error updating PHP code in a node](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21749/strange-error-updating-php-code-in-a-node); as side note, the comment I was trying to edit has not been saved.

Comment: You're saying [this comment](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21749/strange-error-updating-php-code-in-a-node#comment20503_21749) is incorrectly showing an edit, but the edit didn't save?

Comment: I tried twice to edit the comment; the first time, it happened what I described here, while the second time it was successfully saved. What I did was to remove _that_ from "which means you normally call user_permission()"; before, the comment said "which means that you normally call user_permission()." I don't recall if, when I tried the second time, I refreshed the page, or I followed a link to that question to try editing the comment again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your screenshot shows and from looking at the server logs, it seems your browser fetched the home page when trying to save a comment (!).

We're going to have to go with bad/old javascript, maybe from a proxy or our CDN's European node.

If this occurs again, try clearing your browser's cache and trying again.  Also, let me know.